# php mysql result coming back wrong, every time from php, but is fine in sql pro and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

The following statement is returning a 1 in php. I've serialized and output the result and every other credential, and it is doing this on three seperate queries. When I run the query in sqlpro or phpmyadmin I get the result as 8. Please tell me someone has a bright idea.

```
$numRFPsSwitch = 0;
$bquery = " SELECT COUNT(rp.id) AS 'NumRFPs'

   FROM  rfp_proposal rp

   WHERE rp.vendor_id = 1 AND rp.id IN(13,15,16,23,24,26,4,9) ";

$bresult = mysql_query($bquery, $connection); 
$XMLFormatedString .= 'NumRFPs="'; 
while ($brow = mysql_fetch_object($bresult)){ 

$XMLFormatedString .= $brow->NumRFPs; 
$numRFPsSwitch = 1; 
}
```

Comment: Could you add the part where you output the variable that gives you the 1?

Comment: If you could post the details about the output of a var_dump of the row object it may shed some light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could do a `SELECT *` (to return all rows involved), and then do a `mysql_num_rows(...)` on the result to find out the row count. If this returns the same result, then at least you can be sure it's not the query or concatenation that's at fault.

```
$query = "SELECT ...";
echo mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query, $connection));
```

Answer (score 1):

What's returning 1? $numRFPsSwitch which is set to 1? :) $XMLFormatedString should have the correct value, your example works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The result will always be a single row. So the loop should be replaced with an if.
Concerning the problem: Did you check your `$connection`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you use the right login credentials in mysql_connect() and mysql_selectdb()?

Also: If you dó use the right credentials, are you sure you have the right permissions to select/update/delete etc.